# How to sort the significant data in array of minimas?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of local minimas and most of these values are noise and having only few significant values. Let suppose if my vector having three significant values and all are below than then zeros. There is huge difference between significant value and noise. The magnitude of each significant value is also different. I want to sort these significant values in ascending order on basis of their indices. For Example

```
y = [-0.0002, -0.00058, -0.28, -0.0008, -0.25,-0.0006,-0.00004,-0.26]
output = [-0.28, -0.25, -0.26, -0.0002, -0.00058,-0.0008, -0.0006,-0.00004]
```

Somehow, I want to preserve the order to peak indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for you the order in y is more important than a difference of 1/99 (you may tune 1/99 to anything you prefer).

```
[~,order]=sort(y+(1:length(y))/99)
output=y(order)
```

I add the vector [1/99,2/99,3/99,4/99 ...] to y before sorting. Then I only retain the way that modified y would be sorted. And I apply that on the unmodified y.

Won't work if y is very long. For that, you may want to repeat a second time my suggestion:

```
[~,order]=sort(y+(1:length(y))/99)
y=y(order)
[~,order]=sort(y+(1:length(y))/99)
output=y(order)
```

Comment: Please explain it as well. I could not understand the purpose of y+(1:length(y))/99.

Comment: I have 3000 elements in array and your suggested approach is not working.

Comment: Even the long version ? You may also try [~,order]=sort(round(y*100)/100+(1:length(y))*1e-7)